# Codeigniter - cannot upload file .pdf in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I want to upload a pdf file, but that file cannot be uploaded if the file size is over 3 MB

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

$config['max_size'] = '100';

$config['max_width'] = '1024';

$config['max_height'] = '768';
```

Answer (score 0):

The value, you are passing in `max_size` is in `KB`. So you should pass the value in KB. So if you want to restrict that file size should not be greater than 3 MB then you have to pass the value of `max_size` is `3000`. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make 2 changes here

1. add pdf to allowed upload types
2. either remove or increase the max allowed upload size

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';

$config['max_size'] = '10000';

$config['max_width'] = '1024';

$config['max_height'] = '768';
```